# User for automation instead of personal access token

Tags: azure-devops

I have a service hook configured to point to a server which receives a request from Azure Devops every time a pull request is made, which then in turn makes a call to the Azure Devops services REST API to create another pull request.

This second part is done using a PAT (Personal Access Token) for the time being generated from my account. This means that all the pull requests created automatically are made under my name, meaning I receive all the emails and notifications related to this automation.

Is there a way I can create a "fake" identity (without adding an actual user which may authenticate) with a different token which can be used for this automation (opening all pull requests under that identity)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way I can create a "fake" identity (without adding an actual user which may authenticate) with a different token which can be used for this automation (opening all pull requests under that identity)?

Short answer is **no**.

Notification could be setting with three Levels : **Origination,project,personal**. It is not related with the PAT token.

Based on my experience, the Azure Devops also has no way to know which request is automation or manual way to create PR.

So if you don't want to receive the created PR notification, you could disable it on the personal level.

You also could customize the receive emails with project setting to receive the related information.For more information please refer to this [Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/notifications/concepts-events-and-notifications?view=vsts).

[image]

Comment: That is unfortunate as I would like to receive notifications for pull requests I am actually involved in, just not the ones created using my PAT. I shall mark this as the answer until someone provides a workaround for this.